# How to find broken link in Selenium, when a http page have https link and mail address in page body?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I have a http page. Can I verify any broken link when a page has no https link and mail address in the page body.

Is there any way to find the broken link using selenium webdriver in java, when page have multiple https links and mail address in page body ?

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.get("Your page on which links are to be verified");
// Collect all the links into an element.
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
// For each link check repose code is 200.
for (WebElement link : links) {

    String value = link.getAttribute("href");
    // For each link check response code is 200.      
    URL myurl = new URL(value);        
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();        
    connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");         
    int code = connection.getResponseCode();        
    Assert.assertEquals(code, 200);

}
```

Comment: this code will work only when page have all http link nothing else.
Your code have some error.I can not iterate  WebElement links by assigning it string link.I explicitly mention that my page have **https** link(map) and mail link in (a  contact page).

Comment: you code have some fixes:
<!-- language: c# -->
  List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
 
  for (WebElement link : links) {
   
     System.out.println("link "+ link);
     String urlLinks=link.getAttribute("href");
     System.out.println(urlLinks);
     URL myurl = new URL(urlLinks);

Comment: Yup. sorry, I directly wrote code here, should have tested once :p .. updated the code, thanks hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use this tool instead?
[Check my links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/check-my-links/ojkcdipcgfaekbeaelaapakgnjflfglf?hl=en-GB)

If you really want to use Java to detect broken links, below is a suggestion:

1. Build your pages using Page Object Model
2. Identify all of your elements that lead to links and the links' URL
3. In your test, you can write something like, `newURL = webdriver.link.click(), assert (newURL == expectedURL);` this way you can know whether a link is broken.